# Can run `mongod` in foreground but not as daemon

Tags: mongodb

I can run `mongod` normally. But if I run `service mongodb start`, the following error will appear in the log and `mongod` does not start.

```
2016-12-02T01:16:40.804+0200 F INDEX    [initandlisten] Found an invalid index { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" } on the admin.system.version collection: this version of mongod cannot build new indexes of version number 2
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

MongoDB version:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v3.2.11
git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1404
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

UPDATE: Found [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26260). So should I wait for v3.3.15 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clear mongod and restart service

```
$ cd /var/lib
$ sudo rm -rf ./mongodb
$ sudo mkdir mongodb
$ sudo chown -R mongodb.mongodb mongodb/
$ sudo service mongod restart
```

Let me know if you still have problems

Comment: Yes, I actually move `/data/db` (`mongod`'s default) to `/var/lib/mongodb` (`/etc/mongod.conf`'s default).